# "Cannot insert the value NULL", but there is no NULL values!

Tags: sql-server, null

This question follows the answer of my other question there:
[Insert with OUTPUT correlated to sub query table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62854/insert-with-output-correlated-to-sub-query-table)

The Person.LastName column has a NOT NULL constraint. When I execute this code:

```
CREATE TABLE tempIDs
( PersonId INT, 
  FinancialInstitutionId INT
);

MERGE INTO Person 
USING FinancialInstitution AS fi
  ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (CreationDate, AdministrativeStatus, LastName, Street1, Number1, City1, State1, PostCode1, CountryId1, WorkDirectPhone1, Fax1, Email1)
  VALUES (GetDate(), 'Legal', fi.Name, fi.Street, fi.Number, fi.City, fi.[State], fi.PostCode, fi.CountryId, fi.PhoneNumber, fi.Fax, fi.Email)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, fi.Id INTO tempIDs;

UPDATE fi
SET fi.PersonId = t.PersonId
FROM FinancialInstitution AS fi
  JOIN tempIDs AS t
    ON fi.Id = t.FinancialInstitutionId ;
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LastName', table 'Person'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

The thing is that there is no FinancialInstitution.Name that is NULL.

```
SELECT Name FROM FinancialInstitution WHERE Name = NULL
```

This returns no row. Beside, if I replace fi.Name with a value ('A Last Name') the request works.

Comment: It seems to me that FinancialInstitution has no rows at all. After the creation of the table, have you performed any inserts?

Comment: Try this to check for nulls: `SELECT Name FROM FinancialInstitution WHERE Name IS NULL;` or `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE Name IS NULL;`

Comment: Indeed, there are NULL values. Mark Sinkinson is right, and I still see my teacher explaining that a few years ago. I needed my memory refreshed. Sorry I bothered you folks. I'll use the COALESCE. Maybe I should delete this thread?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with these rows (that have NULL in the Name), you can either amend the value (with `COALESCE()` function) or ignore those rows (do not insert them into Person) by altering the `USING` clause in the merge.

Comment: Here I need to amend the value. But if I needed to ignore those rows, I guess you are thinking of simply doing this: USING (SELECT * FROM FinancialInstitution WHERE Name IS NOT NULL) AS fi

Comment: @YugoAmaryl That would work, yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NULL` is not a value. Something cannot '=' NULL

You want:

```
SELECT Name FROM FinancialInstitution WHERE Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Sh** Shame on me! Now I remember my teacher explaining that a few years ago! And that's where COALESCE become useful!

Comment: Or better yet `ISNULL`, as when you are not looking for the first non-null value in a sequence this will be faster. `COALESCE` is treated as a `CASE` statement under the covers, I believe.

Comment: @StevePettifer In this case, he will need a function to simply replace nulls with some non-null value, during an INSERT statement, so there would be no difference in performance.

Comment: @ypercube - Not necessarily true, although the difference seems to be about 10-12% and `ISNULL` also seems to be less CPU intensive ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287642/which-is-quicker-coalesce-or-isnull)), but it is also to case that `ISNULL` is not, strictly speaking, standards compliant being as it is a T-SQL specific implementation, whereas `COALESCE` is part of the SQL standard. Horses for courses though. I prefer the neater syntax of `ISNULL` where you are only testing one value and have no need to support other platforms.