# RETURNING syntax with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, oracle, insert, merge

Again, another question related to the answer of the one there: [Insert with OUTPUT correlated to sub query table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62854/insert-with-output-correlated-to-sub-query-table)

So I ended up with this query, written for SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE tempIDs
( PersonId INT, 
  FinancialInstitutionId INT
);

MERGE INTO Person 
USING FinancialInstitution AS fi
  ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (CreationDate, AdministrativeStatus, LastName, Street1, Number1, City1, State1, PostCode1, CountryId1, WorkDirectPhone1, Fax1, Email1)
  VALUES (GetDate(), 'Legal', fi.Name, fi.Street, fi.Number, fi.City, fi.[State], fi.PostCode, fi.CountryId, fi.PhoneNumber, fi.Fax, fi.Email)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, fi.Id INTO tempIDs;

UPDATE fi
SET fi.PersonId = t.PersonId
FROM FinancialInstitution AS fi
  JOIN tempIDs AS t
    ON fi.Id = t.FinancialInstitutionId ;
```

I am now trying to get an Oracle version working. But I can't find the proper syntax for the `RETURNING` that is supposed to replace `OUTPUT`.

One difference between the two is that `RETURNING` doesn't belong to the `MERGE` but to `INSERT`. I don't think it makes much of a difference here.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_TempID IS RECORD (
       PersonId NUMBER(10,0), 
       FinancialInstitutionId NUMBER(10,0)); 
  TYPE t_TempIDs IS TABLE OF t_TempID;
  t_TempIDs tempIDs;
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO Person p
  USING FinancialInstitution fi ON (1 = 0)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CreationDate, AdministrativeStatus, LastName, Street1, Number1, City1, State1, PostCode1, CountryId1, WorkDirectPhone1, Fax1, Email1)
    VALUES (sysdate, 'Legal', 'fi.Name', fi.Street, 'fi.Number', fi.City, fi.State, fi.PostCode, fi.CountryId, fi.PhoneNumber, fi.Fax, fi.Email)
    RETURNING p.Id, fi.Id INTO tempIDs;

  UPDATE fi
  SET fi.PersonId = t.PersonId
  FROM FinancialInstitution fi
    JOIN tempIDs t
      ON fi.Id = t.FinancialInstitutionId;
END
```

Whatever I try, I get

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

related to the `RETURNING` line.

Comment: As you've said, you cannot use `RETURNING INTO` on a `MERGE` statement in Oracle. You'd need to [flag the change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951649/determining-an-oracle-sql-merge-statement-result) or something similar

Comment: But here I try to use it on the INSERT statement... Can't the nested INSERT query accesses "p" and "fi"?

Comment: That `INSERT` is part of the `MERGE`. The `INSERT` would have to be stand-alone to use `RETURNING`

Comment: I think I'm going to use an iterative version for Oracle...

Comment: You might be better off with `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` and `UPDATE ... WHERE EXISTS ...`.  Never do slow-by-slow when it can be avoided.